# Problem with Atmospheric Correction for Sentinel-2 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2, atmospheric-correction, sentinel

This is my first time trying to use DOS1 method in Sentinel-2
I have four images to mosaic in L1C and need them to be L2A. I have tried:

- Atmospheric correction in QGIS at the L1C files I downloaded and *then* merge them, but have wrong colours in the RGB like so: (Image 1) [image: DOS1 -> mosaic -> RGB]
- After I have the mosaic (and clipped the area of interest) I use the DOS1 method, but the output is too bright: (image 2)[image: mosaic -> clipped -> DOS1 -> RGB]

My results are completely different (all of them with pixel values [0,1]).

**What is the correct way to do atmospheric correction in Sentinel-2 from L1C to L2A?**

Comment: I am not familiar with the DOS1 method so don't know what the expected outcome should be, but it does look like your mosaic has a consistent scale across the two images (since there is no clear line running along the boundary), which suggests something may have run successfully. Is it possible that this issue is related to the display only? I suggest adjusting the symbology to see if your results look reasonable https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/changing_symbology.html

Comment: Thank you, the pixel values are different and wrong. But found a solution with Sen2Cor method, which ESA uses. Still thank tou for replying

Comment: Great, glad you found a solution. You may want to add your solution as an answer to your question to help anyone who has the same question in future

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with Sen2Cor. I go to windows cmd and cd to the file of this processor. I have multiple files to run, so the code it looks like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Sen2Cor-02.11.00-win64>for /d %i in (path\*.SAFE) do L2A_Process.bat %
```